# Multidimensional Array Sorting/Chaining Based on Value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, chaining

I have an array below format:

```
$data = [
  '2018-04-26' => [
    [
      'op' => 3,
      'cl' => 4
    ],
    [
      'op' => 3,
      'cl' => 2
    ],
    [
      'op' => 4,
      'cl' => 3
    ]
  ]
];
```

I want to make it sort as

```
$data['2018-04-26'] = [
    [
      'op' => 3,
      'cl' => 4
    ],
    [
      'op' => 4,
      'cl' => 3
    ],
    [
      'op' => 3,
      'cl' => 2
    ]
];
```

How will I sort based on OP, CL.

- OP of current array is equal to previous array CL. or
- CL of current array is equal to next array OP.
- We can start any where but let start accordingly index 0-n.
- There is no chance for multiple solution.
- If same op/cl appeared we can put it anywhere.

I have tried using **usort()** but how do I put the logic.

```
function cmpare($a, $b){
  //the logic
  return 0;
}
usort($data['2018-04-26'], 'cmpare');
```

Comment: You want to *chain* the values based on previous-next connections? This is a complex problem, starting with the question of where that chain is supposed to start. There may also be multiple solutions or circular chains, how should that be resolved?

Comment: Yes that's the exact problem I am facing.

Comment: So at the very least you'll have to specify answers for my above questions. We don't know how it's *supposed* to work for you.

Comment: Actually first I also think as I posted but after reading your comment I realize the exact problem.

Comment: how can I make my question more specific. My English is not that good. Can you help me.

Comment: Describe how the ordering *should* behave. Where to start, what to do about circular chains or multiple solutions.

Comment: As I mention Ordering is based OP, CL. See my result after sorting/chaining. We can start any where but let start accordingly index 0-n. There is no chance for multiple solution. if same op/cl appeared we can put it anywhere.

Comment: I edited your post since you don't have a question on your post.

Comment: I don't want to spoon feed anyone but I just want to answer and provide what is my take on this so here is my answer.

Comment: `$sorted = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
{
 if (!in_array($key, array_keys($sorted)))
 {
  $sorted[$key] = array();
 }
 if (!in_array($value, $sorted[$key]))
 {
  $sorted[$key] = $value;
 } 
}`

Comment: `foreach ($sorted as $key => $value) {

 usort($value, function($a, $b){
  return $a['cl'] > $b['cl'];
 });
 $sorted[$key] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($sorted);`

Comment: the result is not as I mention.

Comment: Yes I am aware, that is not the exact code for what you want as i stated `i don't want to spoon feed`; you can modify the code to get the output you want.

Comment: BDW Thanks Man. I am already working on this problem. I will share my code if I will get success.

Comment: Please look at this [Click Here]https://repl.it/@thatal/array-chaining-problem . I am working on it.

Answer (score -2):

This is the php code:

```
$data = [];

$data['2018-04-26'][] = [
  'op' => 3,
  'cl' => 4
 ];

 $data['2018-04-26'][] = [
   'op' => 4,
   'cl' => 3
 ];

 $data['2018-04-26'][] = [
    'op' => 3,
    'cl' => 2
 ];


 usort($data['2018-04-26'], function($a, $b){
  return ($a['op'] == $b["cl"]) ? 1 : 0;
 });
```

Comment: Please read the comment posted by **deceze** thats the exact problem.